# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de los comentarios en vscode?

Tags: vscode, configuración

¿Alguien sabe de que manera puedo cambiar el color de los comentarios en *Visual Studio Code*?

Por ejemplo, que cuando escriba el siguiente código, en cualquier lugar, cambie el color a verde

```html
<font color=green>//Esto es un comentario</font>
```

Comment: Te lo hace automaticamente siempre y cuando el comentario sea un comentario valido. En HTML tienes que poner los comentarios encerrados entre `<!--` y `-->` Si usas el keybind CTRL+/ deberia ponerte automaticamente el comentario basandose en tu archivo

Comment: Hay alguna manera que lo resalte de distinta forma, o de cambiar dichos colores? por ejemplo trabajando en PHP los comentarios salen de un color mas oscuro, si quisiera que fueran de color verde o rojo como podría realizar este cambio?

Comment: Debes entrar en el propio archivo settings.json y escribirlo como quieres ahi. Depende de si quieres cambiar los comments para todos los lenguajes, para todos los temas o para algun lenguaje o tema especifico. Hay una respuesta en el sitio en ingles con mucho detalle que te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649255/5866637

Comment: Gracias!, funciono perfectamente!

Comment: @Narshe una traduccion de esa respuesta en el sitio seria de gran ayuda ;)

Comment: Veré que puedo hacer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde el archivo `settings.json`, que puedes abrir mediante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo si deseas cambiar a color rojo define el valor en hexadecimal dentro del archivo `settings.json`:

```
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#ff0000"       
    }
}
```

Esto también puedes configurarlo por tema, revisa que tema estas usando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y define el tema dentro de `settings.json`, en este ejemplo mi tema es `Default Dark+`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma obtendrás el color definido para los comentarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
revisa :

**[Personalizar un tema de color](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)**

revisa también la siguiente respuesta en el sitio en ingles:

[**¿Cómo cambio el color de los comentarios en el código de Visual Studio?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)